# Disabled attribute on input makes it "forget" onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have this JS/HTML

```
<div>
    Are you sure ? <input type="checkbox" id="Confirm" onClick="doCheck();"/>
</div>

<input value="3" id="SubmitT" type="button" onClick="MainFunction(34);" disabled>
```

#edited: typo code

```
function doCheck(){
    $("#SubmitT").prop('disabled',$("#Confirm").is(":checked"));
}
```

What I expect it to do, is set/unset disabled attribute and `MainFunction(34)` to fire or not based on presence of disabled.
What it does is after I toggle checkbox the input it forgets the event binded to onclick, constantly throwing errors about `MainFunction` being unknown.

version of jQuery is 1.11.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are tagged jQuery, it's better to use **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** event handler in jQuery

```js
$('#Confirm').change(function() {
  $("#SubmitT").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Are you sure ?
  <input type="checkbox" id="Confirm"/>
</div>

<input value="3" id="SubmitT" type="button" onClick="MainFunction(34);" disabled>
```

Answer (score 2):

***The code you have shown works fine.***

Are you sure it's not something wrong with your `MainFunction`? Simply using your code and adding a `MainFunction` that simply `alert`s the input works perfectly fine and throws no errors, as shown in the snippet below.

Also, don't you want to be able to click the submit button when the 'Are you sure?' checkbox is checked? To do that, I've changed it to `!$("#Confirm").is(":checked")`.

```js
function doCheck() {
  $("#SubmitT").prop('disabled', !$("#Confirm").is(":checked"));
}

function MainFunction(input) {
  alert(input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Are you sure ?
  <input type="checkbox" id="Confirm" onClick="doCheck();" />
</div>

<input value="3" id="SubmitT" type="button" onClick="MainFunction(34);" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

`document.getElementById('SubmitT').disabled = true;`

so like you're setting it disabled via js.. (do that command on page load) and using the `MainFunction()` control the disabled property.